# ip address 127.0.0.1 cors can't resolve

Tags: reactjs, api, express, google-cloud-platform

[image]

I have a web service architecture on Google cloud platform

if i entered domain(mydomain.com), it's heading to load balancer
and then go to nginx that running on compute engine(virtual machine)

In nginx, proxy indicate 127.0.0.1:3000 and everything works well until now.

127.0.0.1:3000 calling 127.0.0.1:8000 api and cors problem occurs in this moment.

I did apply cors with wild card(*)  but cors problem still in progress

[image]

[image]

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In express you should integrate cors with the specific package.
Something like this

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: I did it for the first time. but it didn't work for me.

I'm using express.js with typescript. is it problem? 

i really don't know why cors happen to me. when i tried to same request using curl, it works well..

Comment: my workflow
```
https://example.com --> gcp loadbalancer -->  virtualmachine --> nginx --> 127.0.0.1:3000 (this point)-->(cors occurs) 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Comment: I don't know if typescript need differents operations. Try to check this guide https://brianflove.com/2017-03-22/express-cors-typescript/